# What are memory mapped file ? describe with a simple example?

Tags: operating-systems

I am not actually getting what memory mapped files are and why we use them and also in which section of operating system do they fit in. please explain with a simple example.

Thanks

Comment: What research have you done, Wikipedia describes this clearly, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file

Answer (score 2):

"Memory-mapped" isn't a file type, it's a way to access it. The same kind of file can be read normally by program A, but memory-mapped by program B.

Normally (in most programming languages), each file access needs a separate call:

- you first `open` the file (getting a "file descriptor"),
- `seek` to the desired position (if necessary),
- `read` a certain amount of bytes (which copies them from file into RAM),
- … `seek`, `read`, `read`, `seek`, `write`, `read`, and so on.

So if you work with e.g. a database file, there's a fair amount of syscalls involved, not to mention all the data copied in & out. (There usually are convenience seek+read and seek+write calls, e.g. `pread` and `pwrite` on Linux, but they don't help much.)

Memory-mapping, meanwhile, lets the program access a file *as if it were RAM*. After `open`ing the file, a program only needs one `mmap` call to set up a memory area, after which it can immediately access the file's contents through that "window" – using a variable reads from the file, changing a variable writes to the file.

This can greatly simplify code as well as speed up file loading and saving, since the program knows the data *will* be there, but the OS doesn't actually have to load it until it's actually needed.

Comment: please wait for a better answer from someone who's actually a programmer